# How to unload the MQ queue records into the file which is of readable format?

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

I have a MQ queue which has 2K odd records which needs to be unloaded into a file and check why these were not consumed by our INBOUND process.
And I tried to unload the records into a file using the below command example:

```
qload -m ABCDE -iQueue1 -f/var/tmp/Queue1.qload
```

And further I tried to zip the file in linux. extarcted it into windows and when I open the file in windows it is not readable.

Could you kindly suggest any command to unload a queue into file with redable form?

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ do you have installed?  qload is meant to output the messages in a format which can be loaded back to a queue and keep the message and MQMD the same but it is not very readable if you just want the text of the messages.   amqsbcg will it output both text and hex of the messages. amqsget will output the text assuming the messages are just ascii formatted (this will also remove them from the queue, you could load them back with your qload back up).

Comment: In what way is it not readable? Is it completely garbage or have you just got extra CR LF characters?

Comment: The output in file is not understandable its has come numbers letters and special characters in the records.

Comment: @JoshMc, thank you. I will try your suggestions and come back for further advise if needed.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, I used the command dspmqinst to get the version, and it is 8.0.0.11

Comment: At that version you should have dspmqmsg available which is a replacement for the original qload, but it still would not help you if you just want to see the contents of the messages.  Did you try the amqsbcg?

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, I tried using this command amqsbcg which displays messages.. I was able to see both hex and text of the messages. But I have around 2260 messages in this queue, so all these records were just filling my screen. Is there a possibility i can load this hex and text data of message into a file and then use this file for further inspection of messages? I used the command like below:  amqsbcg  queuename queue manager > filename . But this didnot work.

Comment: What was the result of the command you tried?

Comment: @JoshMc For the command: amqsbcg queuename queue manager > filename        I got the error like below in the file extract_message_dead_letter_q where I tried capturing the input for my command:                                                                                      

AMQSBCG0 - starts here
**********************

 MQCONNX failed with CompCode:2, Reason:2058
-bash-4.2$

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, I tried the below two commands and it worked like a charm and now the files are in redable format:                          qload -fDEBVRPHV.CIBREP.DEAD.LETTER.qload_1 -fredable_file -dA                    
qload -fDEBVRPHV.CIBREP.DEAD.LETTER.qload_1 -fredable_file_trial -da

Comment: `2058` is `MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR`, this just means the queue manager name is incorrect it someway.   The qload options you found should also work on [`dmpmqmsg`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q117750_.htm) which is build into the MQ install from 8.0 and later.  I mistakenly typed `dspmqmsg` in my earlier comment which does not exist.   This is a good option if you don't mind the extra information.  The java sample `JmsBrowser.java` is another option that would not have the extra information.

Comment: @Sneha you should have a look at [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html) as it is an easy to use GUI application.  You can view the messages as they sit in the queue.  You can also export/offload the messages to either (1) a plain text file or (2) SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below command can be used to make files readble:

```
qload -fDEBVRPHV.CIBREP.DEAD.LETTER.qload_1 -fredable_file -dA 
qload -fDEBVRPHV.CIBREP.DEAD.LETTER.qload_1 -fredable_file_trial -da

where :
-d <Display Options>]
a         Add ASCII columns to HEX file
A         Write output file in ASCII lines rather than HEX
```